# Is there a way to download the gif from discord chat in the mp4 or gif format? I want my discord bot to download the last sent gif in chat

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, gif, animated-gif

the code:

```
@client.command()
async def giffy(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
        if message.attachments:
            for attachment in message.attachments:
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith(('.gif', '.gifv')):
                    gif_url = attachment.url
                    response = requests.get(gif_url)
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                      with open("downloaded.gif", "wb") as f:
                        f.write(response.content)
                    else:
                      print("error")
                    return
        elif message.content:
            content = message.content.lower()
            if content.endswith(('.gif', '.gifv')) or content.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
                  gif_url = content
                  response = requests.get(gif_url)
                  if response.status_code == 200:
                    with open("downloaded.gif", "wb") as f:
                      f.write(response.content)
                  else:
                    print("error")
                  return

    await ctx.send("No GIF found in the channel's history.")
```

this Command finds the last sent gif from the chat and returns the url for it, this feature works fine, but i want to download that gif so that i can use it for some other function, is there a way to download it in gif format or in mp4 format which i can then convert into gif

ps: this code makes a file named as downloaded.gif but that file is always corrupted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `Attachment.save()` method:

```py
@client.command()
async def giffy(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
        if message.attachments:
            for attachment in message.attachments:
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith(('.gif', '.gifv')):
                    await attachment.save("downloaded.gif")
```

Comment: Thanks!! This solved half of my problem, 
BUT
the `content = message.content.lower()` is still in url form, and when I try `await content.save("downloaded.gif")` then it throws and error saying " 'str' object has no attribute 'save' "